# How to configure max number of threads for owin console host

Tags: c#, asp.net, threadpool, asp.net-web-api, owin

I am using the console host to run a web api project, i need to be able to limit the number of threads the app requests from the operating system, at present the more load i throw at the server it gets more and more resources it gets from my machine.

So far i have

```
    static void Main()
    {
        var baseAddress = "http://localhost:9001/"; 

        // Start OWIN host 
        using (WebApp.Start<StartUp>(baseAddress)) {
            Console.ReadLine(); 

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do this in the end i think by just setting the .net threadpool max threads setting